# How i can bind MVC Combobox from Client side with server side data

Tags: combobox, telerik-mvc

I am very new in MVC. I want to bind my combobox with server side data when a user click on a button.

Thanking You
Hasibul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## On Controller Use following code:

```
 public List<ReceiveType> _data = new List<ReceiveType> { 
                new ReceiveType{ReceiveTypeID=1,ReceiveTypeName= "Purchase Order"},
                new ReceiveType{ReceiveTypeID=2,ReceiveTypeName= "Sales Return"},
                new ReceiveType{ReceiveTypeID=3,ReceiveTypeName= "FOC"}
            };

 public string load_cmbBoxWithServerSideDataFromClient() 
        {
          var _List = new SelectList(_data, "ReceiveTypeID", "ReceiveTypeName");
          return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_List);
        }
```

## On View Page Use following code

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("cmbLoadServerData"))
<input type="button" value="load" onclick="load_ServerDataFromClient()" /><br />

function load_ServerDataFromClient() {
        var cmb = $('#cmbLoadServerData').data('tComboBox');

        $.get("/Home/load_cmbBoxWithServerSideDataFromClient", function (response) {

            var selectList = $.parseJSON(response);
            cmb.dataBind(selectList, true);
        });
     }
```